# Its possible to list printers and print via code with ChromeNaCl?

Tags: printing, google-nativeclient

I have a web system that list all client-side printers in a combo, the user select the printer and the system prints the letters in the exctly place to fill a paper form, but this is made in activeX.

- Is there a way to do this in Google NaCl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Pepper API for querying printers. You should query printers from your app's web page. In Chrome, use the printerProvider API.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/printerProvider